# Is Avro Schema Registry compatibility lost when using arrays?

Tags: avro, confluent-schema-registry

I'm using Confluent Avro Schema Registry with backward compatibility option. I upload this schema which is a record inside an array (the [ ]-brackets). This record only contains one string field.

```
curl -X POST -i -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json" --data '{"schema": "[{\"type\": \"record\", \"name\": \"TestRecord\", \"namespace\": \"com.company\", \"fields\": [{\"name\": \"testname\", \"type\": \"string\"}]}]"}' http://localhost:8081/subjects/test99-value/versions
```

Everything goes well and I get a success response back (200).

Now I want to sanity check this so I remove the string field and I add a integer field. This should definitely not be compatible, neither forward nor backwards.

```
curl -X POST -i -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json" --data '{"schema": "[{\"type\": \"record\", \"name\": \"TestRecord\", \"namespace\": \"com.company\", \"fields\": [{\"name\": \"testname2\", \"type\": \"int\"}]}]"}' http://localhost:8081/subjects/test99-value/versions
```

The problem is that this also returns a success even though this cannot possibly be correct. Am I missing something very basic here?

If I do this with a record that isn't inside an array I get the expected error from the schema registry.

Comment: That isn't a Valid Avro schema with the square brackets... Is that actually being stored?

Comment: Yes, the schema is being stored. I can curl GET on /subjects/test99-value/versions/1 and get the schema returned: `{"subject":"test99-value","version":1,"id":5,"schema":"[{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"TestRecord\",\"namespace\":\"com.company\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"testname\",\"type\":\"string\"}]}]"}`

Comment: Hmm. I see in the Avro spec that an array just represents a union. So you didn't remove a string field and add an int... You replaced a whole record type within the union. The real test would be trying to read records of that new schema.